# How to use custom list view with bottom navigation bar in android java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, native

Unable to use bottom navigation in this code on full page on list view is visible

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@font/montserrat_regular_400"
        tools:context=".AddedDevicesActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </ListView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Unable to use bottom navigation in this code, On full page only list view is visible.

Comment: Do you notice that both the views have the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`?? They are overlapping each other. And since you are new here, dont forget to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavigationBar"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_item">
</ListView>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
```

Comment: **Not working**

Comment: Answer edited try now